# How to remove a large indentation (padding) under the embed video?

Tags: html, css, embed

A large indent under the video is formed:
https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/e8c751a1-34b3-4ca8-9130-ed78e6558b71.png

```
<div class="embed-responsive"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QILiHiTD3uc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
```

@media (min-width:1200px) {

```
  .embed-responsive {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;  
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item,
.embed-responsive iframe,
.embed-responsive embed,
.embed-responsive object,
.embed-responsive video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

}

At lower resolution, standard code (without 80%) works correctly:

```
    .embed-responsive {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;  
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item,
.embed-responsive iframe,
.embed-responsive embed,
.embed-responsive object,
.embed-responsive video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: probably `padding-bottom: 56.25%;`

Comment: nope, if we delete this string, videos go away, hidden

Comment: at least provide a working a example, so people can debug it.